# How to make a multi page registration process in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, submit

I have a concept for how to make a multiple page registration route on my Laravel app, but there is still one area that I can't find. When the user begins to register, the registration route is called. Inside of the register route, multiple views are linked to each other on if statements. For instance, if the user completes one view for the registration, then return the view for the next part of the registration process. The user will continue navigating the routes within the registration process until completed. What I'm trying to find is how to notify the program that the user has completed a view through submitting their information to the app database. Is their a function that allows this to be notified?

Here is a pseudo code format of the route and possible a controller function:

```
Route posting of register, (possible controller function)
if user completes first section
    return next section view 
if user completes second section 
    return next section view 
if user completes third section 
    return next final view 
if user completes final section 
    redirect to different route
end
```

end

If someone could answer this, I can type the functions and routes for this structure very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Session to store the values. Let me tell you how.

> Route: register/step/1 (use whatever you want)

- User Enters The information.
- Store it in Session using
  `session()->put('key','value');`.
- Redirect to step 2.

> Route: register/step/2

- User Enters the Information.
- Store it in Session using `session()->put('key','value');`.
- Redirect to step n.

.
.

> Route: register/step/n

- User Enters the Information.
- Store it in Session using `session()->put('key','value');`.
- Redirect to step n+1.

Now, At last, You can get data from Session using `session()->get('key');` and process it and store it in Database or do whatever you want.

According to me, it's the best way to make multi-page registration using Laravel.

Let me know if this helps! Also let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: It looks like it works. I just need to understand what exactly would be put as the key and the value, even outside of my example. Would there only be one key and value data? And how would I tie that to the present route mentioned?

Comment: After a little research, I found how to do this. Thank you very much!